# How do I find the maximum number of options for a month in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to find out the maximum number of rate options in a given month for each of my users. Here is what my rates table looks like:

```
Member  | Month     |   Rate
Joe     | Jan       |   1
Joe     | Jan       |   2
Joe     | Jan       |   3
Joe     | Feb       |   1
Joe     | Feb       |   2
Joe     | Feb       |   2
Joe     | Mar       |   1
Joe     | Mar       |   2
Joe     | Mar       |   2
Max     | Jan       |   1
Max     | Jan       |   1
Max     | Jan       |   1
Max     | Feb       |   2
Max     | Feb       |   2
Max     | Feb       |   2
Max     | Mar       |   3
Max     | Mar       |   3
Max     | Mar       |   3
Ben     | Jan       |   1
Ben     | Jan       |   2
Ben     | Jan       |   2
Ben     | Feb       |   1
Ben     | Feb       |   1
Ben     | Feb       |   1
Ben     | Mar       |   1
Ben     | Mar       |   1
Ben     | Mar       |   1
```

Joe, in January, has rate options [1,2,3] available for him. Joe, in February and March, only has two [1,2]. For each user, I'd like to display the maximum number of rates available in one month (compared for all months). The outcome table should look like this:

```
Member | Max rates in one month
Joe    | 3
Max    | 1
Ben    | 2
```

How would I write this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to group on member and month and count the rates:

```
SELECT "Member", "Month", count(*) AS n FROM rates GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Now that you have the count of rates per-member per-month, you can use the result to extract the maximum value for every member:

```
SELECT "Member", max(n) FROM (
    SELECT "Member", "Month", count(*) AS n FROM rates GROUP BY 1,2) X
 GROUP BY "Member";
```

The are other methods using, for example, window functions but the idea is always the same and I think the code above makes it clear what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some aggregation:

```
SELECT Member, MAX(rate_count) as "Max rates in one month"
FROM 
    (SELECT Member, Month, COUNT(DISTINCT RATE) rate_count FROM yourtable GROUP BY Member, Month) dt
GROUP BY Member;
```